# How to retrieve the file path column "ows_EncodedAbsUrl" in search result.

Tags: sharepoint, url, search

I am passing the search query in to search.asmx to get the search value.

Through web services I am retrieving the search result. Search result will return document path for .txt files and image. This path used to open the file directly.

txt file: "http://server:24669/jap/ww.txt- It will open the file.

PDF File:"http://server:100/456efg/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=3&RootFolder=/456efg"- It will show PDF properties or parent folder.

So I need to Get the Url to open the PDF doc. "ows_EncodedAbsUrl" column have the document URL but it’s not retrievable  in search result. Is there any way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a PDF iFilter to your SharePoint environment, PDF files will no longer be treated as list items (thus the property view link).

Of course Adobe post the [instructions](http://www.adobe.com/special/acrobat/configuring_pdf_ifilter_for_ms_sharepoint_2007.pdf) for this as a PDF.

This change will also start indexing the text of your PDF documents so they will be more searchable. Be aware that if a percentage of the PDF documents size will be added to your search storage costs, so [plan ahead](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262971.aspx).

This is a cure for the symptom, I do not know if there are other ways to do this.